# Extracting some data from XML

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<block1>
  <tag>
    <name>59</name>
    <value>/00940001812410930828 FONDITEL VALORES AV SAU ATAM PEDRO TEIXERIA 8 PLANTA 7A 28020MADRID
    </value>
  </tag>
</block1>
```

I need the output as `00940001812410930828 ,FONDITEL VALORES AV SAU ATAM PEDRO TEIXERIA 8 PLANTA 7A 28020MADRID`

Can any one help me please?

Comment: You've tagged the question as XML but then given an example of what looks like a space separated values. You will most likely need regex for this, unless you know that the string in position 1 will always be mapped to position 4 in the output etc. EDIT: Showing xml now.

Comment: To post code use the `{}` button, or put four spaces before each line. You can also visit the [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not missing anything try the following approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="//value">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after('/', normalize-space(.))"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In case you want to concentrate on string processing you should probably consider improving your xml markup instead of that. Otherwise working with string values with xslt 1.0 is tedious. (if you're using 2.0 then there is a list of predefined functions exactly for this purpose (like [fn:tokenize](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize)).

Comment: <xsl:for-each select="block4/tag[name ='50k']">   
    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>,<xsl:text/>
   </xsl:for-each> 
is it corrected way writing like this ....because in my block so many tags are there so i need to call each tag can any one help me

Comment: <xsl:for-each select="block4/tag[name ='50k']">   
    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>,<xsl:text/>
   </xsl:for-each> 
is it corrected way writing like this ....because in my block so many tags are there so i need to call each tag can any one help me

Comment: No, `xsl:for-each` is considered not xslt-style construct. It's imperative. In XSLT you'd better "push" nodes with `<xsl:apply-templates select="block4/tag[name='50k']" mode="handle-50k-blocks`/>` and handle them with another template `<xsl:template match="block4" mode="handle-50k-blocks">...`.

Comment: Two minors: starting `//` operator in pattern is not needed; `xsl:for-each` it's an iterator, it's not imperative. Of course, it isn't as powerful as polymorphic `xsl:apply-templates`, but it has the advantage of not polluting the calls stack.

Comment: I didn't notice, but you have missed the `,` comma

Answer (score 1):

This XPath expression:

```
concat(
   substring-after(
      substring-before(
         /block1/tag/value,
         ' '
      ),
      '/'
   ),
   ' ,',
   substring-after(
      /block1/tag/value,
      ' '
   )
)
```

Or this XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(
                                 substring-before(
                                    /block1/tag/value,
                                    ' '
                                 ),
                                 '/'
                              )"/>
        <xsl:text> ,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(
                                 /block1/tag/value,
                                 ' '
                              )"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And a simple XPath 2.0 expression:

```
replace(/block1/tag/value,'/([^ ]* )(.*)','$1,$2')
```

Comment: @Alejandro, I've made it with purpose because I was in doubt whether this comma is general case or typo. To cover this situation I've prompted to change xml format in order to make transformations more readable and simple. With XSLT 1.0 I never seen general solutions for parsing strings (only application specific recursion with tokenized by some rule string). +1 for full solution.