# how to get particular value

Tags: xml, xslt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extracting some data from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003858/extracting-some-data-from-xml)

```
<block1>
  <tag>
    <name>59</name>
    <value>/00940001812410930828 FONDITEL VALORES AV SAU ATAM PEDRO TEIXERIA 8 PLANTA 7A 28020MADRID
    </value>
  </tag>
</block1>
```

xslt

```
  <xsl:for-each select="block4/tag[name ='59']">         
      <xsl:value-of select="value"/>,<xsl:text/>
   </xsl:for-each>
```

is it corrected way writing like this ....because in my block so many tags are there so i need to call each tag can any one help me

i need output like :

```
/00940001812410930828 , FONDITEL VALORES AV SAU ATAM PEDRO TEIXERIA 8 PLANTA 7A 28020MADRID
```

Comment: Can you please edit and frame the question neatly by posing your whole XML data

Comment: Please don't keep re-posting the same question over and over again!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to load the XML into an XML parser e.g. [XDocument:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx)

A sample code

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse("SomeXml");
string Yourrequiredtag= xdoc.Descendants("requiredtag").First().Value;
```

Like this find all the required tags and display data

Try this articles

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256166.aspx

http://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial/xslt_for-each.cfm

Comment: can yu please help in tht xslt ..!! i need in xslt

Comment: You said that you need 00940001812410930828 FONDITEL VALORES AV SAU ATAM PEDRO TEIXERIA 8 PLANTA 7A 28020MADRID so as per my given code write your tag there in place of requiredtag you may get

Comment: @dorababu ..no bro ...i xml always looks like this .i hv to write a xslt for that to divide in to halfs

Comment: Have you checked the articles regarding xslt what i posted

Comment: Post the complete XML and XSLT files so that i may check as per you need

Comment: but i dint find wht i hv required bro ! i hv tried like this way but it not working  <xsl:value-of select="substring-after('/', normalize-space(.))"/>

Answer (score 0):

You're complaining that the code you are writing is repetitive. Well, when code looks repetitive, there's nearly always a way of abstracting it to avoid tedious repetition. This comes down to looking at the repetitive code, to see what's common and what can therefore be factored out. The problem is, you've only shown us one instance of your repetitive code. You haven't shown us enough data and enough code so that we can see the pattern emerging.

(XSLT 2.0 is better at this than 1.0. But even with 1.0, I once reduced a client's stylesheet from 1000 lines of code to 20 lines by rewriting it at a higher level of abstraction).