# check for first white space and replace by ,

Tags: xml, xslt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extracting some data from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003858/extracting-some-data-from-xml)

```
<block1>
  <tag>
    <name>59</name>
    <value>/00940001812410930828 FONDITEL VALORES AV SAU ATAM PEDRO TEIXERIA 8 PLANTA 7A 28020MADRID
    </value>
  </tag>
</block1>
```

output should look like this :

> /00940001812410930828, FONDITEL VALORES AV SAU ATAM PEDRO TEIXERIA 8 PLANTA 7A 28020MADRID

Comment: hello can you please help me man i need to search for the first space and there i have to replace by comma

Answer (score 1):

Try this

http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/06/05/transforming.html

Comment: hello bro here i need to search for the first space and there i hv to replace a comma over there